# blockchain.info does not want to import my bcc private key

Tags: blockchain.info

I imported my BCC private key into blockchain.info. But it does not ask me for the private key and lists the address as 'watch only'. I'd like to import the BCC amount into a blockchain.info wallet. All Tutorials about it do not correspond with the current blockchain menus.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I used btc.com wallet instead of blockchain.com. 
btc.com worked fine!